# ffmpeg does not apply watermark on first generated frame (wm is applied on all other frames)

Tags: ffmpeg, watermark

I am generating a bunch of jpgs from a movie, and want the watermark to be applied to
all the jpgs.
This works fine for all frames, but the first one, and I cannot figure out why.

This is the command I use

```
ffmpeg -vframes 16 -ss 00:00:01 -i a.mov -t 00:00:17 -r 1 -s 1280x720 -vf "movie=watermark.png,scale=1280:720 [wm];[in][wm] overlay=0:0 [out]" '/tmp/output%d.jpg'
```

which will give me these files:

```
output1.jpg
output2.jpg
output3.jpg
output4.jpg
output5.jpg
output6.jpg
output7.jpg
output8.jpg
output9.jpg
output10.jpg
```

where they all BUT output1.jpg has got watermark applied.

I cannot figure out why ffmpeg does not apply the watermark on the first one.

I am using ffmpeg 1.2 on debian

Comment: Unrelated: You can add `-i watermark.png` and eliminate the `movie` multimedia source filter if you use `-filter_complex` instead of `-vf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `-ss` before `-i`, it will seek to a keyframe.  This is quick, but if there is not a keyframe at the specified time then it is not frame-accurate and you may end up with some frames before the seek time, which will effectively have negative timestamps.  Since your watermark movie overlay starts at time 0, the frames with negative timestamps will not have a watermark.

If you move the `-ss` option after the input file, this is slower because it must process and discard all of the frames up to that point, but it will seek to the precise timestamp that you specify and not leave you with frames before the specified time.

Another option is to stick to the fast keyframe-based seeking and then use the `select` filter to eliminate any undesired frames.  For example:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:01 -i a.mov -t 00:00:17 -r 1 -s 1280x720 -vf "[in] select=gte(t\,0) [sel];movie=watermark.png,scale=1280:720 [wm];[sel][wm] overlay=0:0 [out]" '/tmp/output%d.jpg'
```

Comment: ah, very interesting! One question
"Since your watermark movie overlay starts at time 0"

is it possible to tell ffpmeg to take all, also the negative timestamps?

Comment: @JohnSmith: In general, `movie=` provides multiple frames.  It has to start at some time.  You could use the `setpts` filter to shift the `movie=` to start earlier, if you knew how much to shift.  But removing the negative portions with `select` is better since the start frame will then be closer to what was requested.